# Swift get data from local JSON file and load into Tableview

Tags: swift

My scenario, I am trying to load local `JSON` file data Into `tableview`. Here, I would like to know which is proper method for referring local JSON file and how to use it simply using `struct` and `codable` to load Into Tableview.

I would like to know below details and sample code with highly professional method.

How to call my JSON file in a proper way and need to get the data from JSON file with help of struct and Codable to load in tableview?

My JSON File

```
[{
    "flag": "usa.png",
    "country": "USA",
    "countryName": "United States"
}, {
    "flag": "india.png",
    "country": "IND",
    "countryName": "India"
}, {
    "flag": "uk.png",
    "country": "UK",
    "countryName": "United Kingdom"
}]
```

My Code

```
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "sample", ofType: "json") {
    do {
          let data = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path), options: .mappedIfSafe)
          let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableLeaves)
          if let jsonResult = jsonResult as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>, let person = jsonResult["person"] as? [Any] {
          }
      } catch {
      }
}
```

Comment: You can generate a codable struct with quicktype.io. And yes that is the correct way of getting the data of a local json file.

Comment: You have asked 3 questions rather than 1 and for each of those questions you can easily find the answer with a very small research effort since there are many tutorials and articles online covering these subjects.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Its just for clarification I mentioned 3 questions. But actually it is one question. Please upvote my question.

Comment: You can merge that into one question that then becomes too broad. The down vote is for the lack of research, not the number of questions.

Comment: In your code there is a key `person`. Where is `person` in the JSON? And why not `Bundle.main.url(forResource: "sample", withExtension: "json")` as your need URL anyway?

Answer (score 2):

You can first create a struct with codable to match your json format

```
struct CountryModel: Codable{
let flag: String
let country: String
let countryName: String

 }
```

And json read file as

```
func readJson(){
    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "sample", ofType: "json") {
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path), options: .mappedIfSafe)
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            do {
   // get the data from JSON file with help of struct and Codable 
                let countryModel = try decoder.decode([CountryModel].self, from: data)
   // from here you can populate data in tableview
                print(countryModel)

            }catch{
                print(error) // shows error
                print("Decoding failed")// local message
            }

        } catch {
            print(error) // shows error
            print("Unable to read file")// local message
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Vikky. Btw In your code multiple do catch we can see. Can you make it simple?

Comment: I have printed the error statements to make things easier to understand. If you don't care of actual errors you can remove do catch and use try?.

Comment: Poor error handling, print `error` and never `error.localizedDescription`, and even worse advise in the comments about using `try?`.

Comment: `error.localizedDescription` does **not** *show actual error*. It shows a generic meaningless error message. Especially in a `JSONDecoder` `catch` block print always only `error`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I show all prints this way because OP was asking to make do catch simple to understand.More ever I said if you Don't care for errors use try?, and yes you are correct it is worse advice to do so

Comment: @vadian Yes you are right I just wanted to make thing easier to understand

Answer (score 0):

Use following code

```
class DummyDataModel {
var flag:String?
var country:String?
var countryName:String?
static func setingModelValues(_ values: JSON)->DummyDataModel {
    let dataModel = DummyDataModel()
    dataModel.flag = values["flag"].stringValue
    dataModel.country = values["country"].stringValue
    dataModel.countryName = values["countryName"].stringValue
    return dataModel
}}

class SampleClass: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var mainTableView: UITableView! {
    didSet {
        mainTableView.delegate = self
        mainTableView.dataSource = self
        mainTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 200
        mainTableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
}
var dummyDataModel = [DummyDataModel]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.gettingJsonDataValue()

}
private func gettingJsonDataValue() {
    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "sample", ofType: "json") {
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path), options: .mappedIfSafe)
            let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableLeaves)
            let jsonResponse = try JSON(data: data)
            for myData in jsonResponse.arrayValue {
                let instadata = DummyDataModel.setingModelValues(myData)
                self.dummyDataModel.append(instadata)
            }
            self.mainTableView.reloadData()

        } catch {
            // handle error
        }

    }}
extension SampleClass: UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dummyDataModel.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let sampleCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SampleCell") as! SampleCell
        sampleCell.gettingUiUpdate(dummyDataModel[indexPath.row])
        return sampleCell
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
    }
```

Comment: Why not use `Codeable`?